# Can you restore multiple Oracle databases with the same tablespace name?

Tags: oracle, database-restore

I am in the process of setting up an Oracle instance for customer database restores.

The vast majority of our customers use the same tablespace name for their databases, which leads to us needing a separate DB instance for every restore.

Is there a way we could re-map tablespace names or have multiple withg the same name within a single Oracle install?

For example could we take the tablespace name "serverfault" which 10 customers use and restore as serverfault1, serverfault2 etc. from the DMP files?

It's terribly wasteful to have a full Oracle instance for every single DB restored.

I'm aware you can do FROMUSER TOUSER if the usernames clash, but haven't found a way to sort our issue with tablespace clashes.

Answer (score 0):

Data Pump can remap tablespaces during an import, as specified in the REMAP_TABLESPACE parameter: [REMAP_TABLESPACE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17639/dp_import.htm#SUTIL3193)

Unfortunately it seems you use the old method for export/import, which does not offer this feature.